# How can I make Windows 10 use the same DNS which is used on my phone?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, android, mobile-hotspot

I would like to know, how can I make Windows 10 use the same DNS which my phone is using?

I use my phone as a hotspot and even if I change my DNS to the one that I want to use, the laptop does not use it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you changing the DNS? You will need to change it on the Windows 10 system, not the phone.

Comment: I was changing it on the phone... May you please explain how I can changing the DNS on my laptop? Thanks for helping!!

Comment: You will need to go into the Network Adapter settings on the Windows 10 system; this is not for the inexperienced to do. Why do you need to change the DNS settings?

Comment: I am still a teenager (almost 16) and my ISP keeps showing me ads of nude images on various ads. I know that it is my ISP because most of the time, they show ads about the company. If I switch to 1.1.1.1 as my DNS on my phone, I no longer see those ads all the time.

Comment: Your ISP is probably hijacking your DNS. In which case the only solution is to complain and probably change to another ISP.